# How to give Word2Vec vector to classifier in python?

Tags: python, classification, word2vec, word-embedding

my code in python is for multi-label classifying; using TF-IDF vectorizer for a bunch of tweets. i just put the corresponding part of the code below. my vocab is a 14182 words lexicon and the train_array.shape is (6838,14182). also the train_labels.shape is (6838, 11):

```
#Vectorizing
vector_maker = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words= set(stopwords.words('english')), vocabulary= vocab) #Vectorizer
train_array = vector_maker.fit_transform(train_tweets).toarray() #Making vector for train tweets
test_array = vector_maker.fit_transform(test_tweets).toarray() #Making vector for test tweets

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_array,train_labels)
predicted= clf.predict(test_array)
print("Accuracy = ",accuracy_score(test_gold_labels,predicted))
```

the code works well. now i want to use Word2Vec as vectorizer. i changed the code to:

```
#Vectorizing 
vector_maker = Word2Vec(vocab, size=50, window=5, min_count=1, workers=8) #Vectorizer
train_array = vector_maker.train(train_tweets, total_examples=vector_maker.corpus_count, epochs=15) #Making vector for train tweets
test_array = vector_maker.train(test_tweets, total_examples=vector_maker.corpus_count, epochs=15) #Making vector for test tweets

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_array,train_labels)
predicted= clf.predict(test_array)
print("Accuracy = ",accuracy_score(test_gold_labels,predicted))
```

then i get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3977a56bf1df> in <module>
     71 #clf = RandomForestClassifier()
     72 clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
---> 73 clf.fit(train_array,train_labels)
     74 predicted= clf.predict(test_array)
     75 print("Accuracy = ",accuracy_score(test_gold_labels,predicted))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    814             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    815             check_input=check_input,
--> 816             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    817         return self
    818 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    128         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    129         if check_input:
--> 130             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    131             y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    132             if issparse(X):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    519                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    520                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 521                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    522 
    523         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1249397. 9119055.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

then i find out that train_array isn't a array. i mean i find out that for getting trained vectors of Word2Vec you should use vector_maker.wv.vectors. but first i tried this to see the vectors dimension:

```
print(vector_maker.wv.vectors.shape)
```

but i get (30, 50). shouldn't i get (6838,50)? or what? actually i don't know so much about how Word2Vec works. i read many but didn't get so much. 
can you guys tell me what should i do to use created vectors for classifying?

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-`.fit()` your `TfidfVectorizer` to your test data: it will change the word-indexes & weights to match test data. Rather, fit on the training data, then use the same train-data-fit model on the test data, to reflect the fact you're analyzing the test data only based on what was learned without it, and the have compatible

Your code isn't using the gensim `Word2Vec` class properly:

- what is 'vocab'? (The `Word2Vec` class needs either an iterable training corpus of already-tokenized text there, or nothing at all so that you can do later steps manually. It doesn't take anything that'd be described as a `vocab`, and you've not shown what `vocab` is, and if you did supply a corpus into the `Word2Vec()` instantiation, you wouldn't then call `train()` on that model.)
- .`train()` doesn't return arrays corresponding to either each text, or each word: just some summary numbers about training. You have to later ask the model for each learned word-vector that you need. And, word-vectors aren't summaries of multi-word texts (unless you do something like average them together).
- It's not clear if you've pre-tokenized the texts into lists-of-words, as `Word2Vec` requires. If you've passed raw strings, instead of word-tokens, the model will learn nonsense vectors for each character. If there are only 30 unique characters in your texts, that would explain a `model.wv.vectors.shape` of `(30, 50)`: you've created exactly 30 word-vectors of 50 dimensions each.

Your code is far enough from working that your best bet would be to work through some functional `Word2Vec` documentation-tutorials, to see the right way to use it, before trying to embed it into a larger `scikit-learn` training pipeline. See for example an OK intro notebook from a prior version of gensim:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ff107d6c5cb50d9ab99999cb898ff0aceb192592/docs/notebooks/word2vec.ipynb

Comment: About training my test data: i didn't get your meant exactly. i used tfidf vectorizer to create vectors from test data (which are raw tweets). you said don't use on them? so how to create vector from them? can you change the code? i can't understand.

Comment: and about word2vec: i said what vocab is. it's a lexicon made of 14182 tokenized and unique words. NRC Emotion Lexicon. i thought word2vec needs lexicon for creating vectors. frankly i want to do with word2vec the same thing i did with tfidf. and worth noting that i pre-processed and tokenized the tweets before. then aggregate all tokens into a tweet again (per tweet). i did this to put them into tfidf vectorizer (because it works on a list of tweets not words). but now it seems Word2Vec needs an array or tokenized words, not sentences.

Comment: now would you please tell me how to connect each tweet to it's corresponding labels? cause i'm doing a multi-label classification. you said something about averaging which i didn't understand. for now you assume that i have a single label classification problem. how to connect each tweet to it's label in training phase? as you can see i did this with the classifier (in TF-IDF). should i do this for Word2Vec too? if so, how? thanks in advance. i really have no one to help me.

Comment: Have you worked through the word2vec tutorial I highlighted? (And ideally: others online, so you better understand what it can and can't do.) Note again that word2vec alone only gives vectors for words, not full texts (tweets). And that word2vec alone doesn't provide classification - it might just be one early step that helps deliver features for classification. Other than that, I can't talk your through every step or write code for you.

Comment: Your best bet is to work through many tutorials of word2vec & classification, then adapt their techniques to your problem, and then, only when stuck on a specific step, ask a very-focused question (here or similar places) with as much detail as possible about what you've tried, what you expected (from other working examples), and what you saw instead.

Comment: Ok thanks mate, i'm reading tutorials. but could you please answer my first question? this----> About training my test data: i didn't get your meant exactly. i used tfidf vectorizer to create vectors from test data (which are raw tweets). you said don't use on them? so how to create vector from them? can you change the code? i can't understand

Comment: I don't understand your question. "how to create vector from them" – what's "them"? No, I can't change the code – it's too far from any working example.

Comment: The first part of my code is separate from the second part. i ran the first part which is using TF-IDF and worked properly and i got Accuracy score of 28. but you said: Don't re-.fit() your TfidfVectorizer to your test data. what do you mean by Refit? i just fit it once. you said: Rather, fit on the training data, then use the same train-data-fit model on the test data. now my question is: what do you mean by this? how could it be possible to use train data vectors for test data? can you explain your meant in a code? i don't want the entire code, just say your word in code.

Comment: Can you check my new answer now? i got what you mean about TF-IDF. can you check it if it's true?

Comment: I can't talk you through every step here. You should be working from more basic tutorials of each step until you understand. When you hit very specific blocks/unexpected-results, it may be appropriate to post them as standalone questions, with all necessary code/info to see what you've tried, what you expected, and what you saw instead.

Comment: This is third time i ask you to explain your previous answer and you only try to convince me to read more. i am reading, but why you're making this so hard? i just want you to explain your answer more clear, idk what is wrong with it. this answer of you isn't clear and i cannot find any tutorial to learn this to me. is it really hard for you to just make your explanation a bit clear??

Comment: this-----> Don't re-.fit() your TfidfVectorizer to your test data: it will change the word-indexes & weights to match test data. Rather, fit on the training data, then use the same train-data-fit model on the test data, to reflect the fact you're analyzing the test data only based on what was learned without it, and the have compatible----- do you mean that i should use .transform function instead of .fit_transform for test_data? or what? let me know the correct path.

Comment: Yes. If you're re-fitting on your test data, you're (1) discarding all the things learned from the training data; and (2) if later evaluating that module fit-on-test-data, no longer maintaining the proper train/test separation for useful evaluations. This is a very foundational error, so the proper step is to work through a number of intro articles/tutorials on similar scikit-learn pipelines until you understand the core concepts/steps of an ML pipeline. Until you do that, you'll be very frustrated – as will the people who try to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
#Vectorizing
vector_maker = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words= set(stopwords.words('english')), vocabulary= vocab) #Vectorizer
train_array = vector_maker.fit_transform(train_tweets).toarray() #Making vector for train tweets
test_array = vector_maker.transform(test_tweets).toarray()

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(train_array,train_labels)
predicted= clf.predict(test_array)
print("Accuracy = ",accuracy_score(test_gold_labels,predicted))
```

Comment: @gojomo My friend, can you check the TF-IDF now? is it ok?

Comment: You shouldn't be posting code blocks without explanations, and asking for feedback, as "answers". If your question needs further improvement, you can edit it in-place.